# How do I create a Flyway migration that runs after the app boots and uses another service?

Tags: java, mysql, database-migration, flyway

I just added a new `time_zone` column into a `user` table, now I need to populate it for all existing records.

The values are supposed to be figured out based on another column `postal_code` in the same table.

The conversion is done by a geo service called [OpenCage](https://opencagedata.com/).

So I want to create a new Flyway migration, which

1. reads every line of the table, gets its `postal_code` value,
2. calls the geo service's API and passes the `postal_code` value to it.
3. receives the returned time zone,
4. and store it in the `time_zone` column.

The geo service is a SpringBoot `@Service` in my app, so in the migration class, I need to `@Autowired` it.

And I think this migration needs to run automatically right after the app boots, instead of using commmand `flyway:migrate`.

My current implementation is like below, **the issue is it doesn't run after the app boots**.

```
public class V151__CalculateTimeZoneForExistingUsers extends BaseJavaMigration {
    @Autowired
    private GeocodingService geocodingService;

    public void migrate(Context context) throws Exception {
        try (Statement select = context.getConnection().createStatement()) {
            try (ResultSet rows = select.executeQuery("SELECT id, postal_code FROM user")) {
                while (rows.next()) {
                    long id = rows.getLong(1);
                    String postalCode = rows.getString(2);

                    JOpenCageResult jOpenCageResult = geocodingService.geocode(postalCode);
                    if (jOpenCageResult != null && jOpenCageResult.getAnnotations() != null && jOpenCageResult.getAnnotations().getTimeZone() != null) {
                        String timeZone = jOpenCageResult.getAnnotations().getTimeZone().getName();
                        try (Statement update = context.getConnection().createStatement()) {
                            update.execute("UPDATE user SET time_zone = '" + timeZone + "' WHERE id=" + id);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is in the package of `src\main\java\org\LayerOne\LayerTwo\db\migration\V151__CalculateTimeZoneForExistingUsers.java`

In `pom.xml`, the configuration for flyway is

```
                <configuration>
                    <user>username</user>
                    <password>password</password>
                    <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB</url>
                    <baselineOnMigrate>true</baselineOnMigrate>
                    <baselineVersion>0.0</baselineVersion>
                    <locations>
                        <location>classpath:db/migration, classpath:org/LayerOne/LayerTwo/db/migration</location>
                    </locations>
                </configuration>
```

Using `flyway:info`, I can see the migration is listed. But it doesn't run after the app boots.

Could anyone teach me how to make it run?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your `@Service`? If Spring Boot, add that tag to your Queation.

Comment: @BasilBourque Done. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I only need to add the Springboot annotation `@Component` to the class like

```
@Component
public class V151__CalculateTimeZoneForExistingUsers extends BaseJavaMigration {
...
}
```

Then it will run after the app boots